# Scrolling issues with pywinauto

Tags: python, pywinauto

I'm trying to scroll in an excel document (using pywinauto) and it doesn't seem to work.

Code:

```
app = Application(backend="uia").connect(process=8876)
win = app.top_window()
win.set_focus()
win.wheel_mouse_input(wheel_dist=10)
```

The *set_focus* works but the scrolling doesn't, I also tried playing with the *wheel_dist* with no success.

Another question, Is there a way to scroll Right/Left?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it by using *pywinauto.mouse* directly instead of using *wheel_mouse_input* through the window object. I also needed to find the right coords. So this is the new code:

```
app = Application(backend="uia").connect(process=8876)
win = app.top_window()
win.set_focus()
win_rect = win.rectangle()
coords = (random.randint(win_rect.left, win_rect.right), random.randint(win_rect.top, win_rect.bottom))
pywinauto.mouse.scroll(coords=coords, wheel_dist=10)
```

I solved the "right/left scrolling" by using the *pyautogui* library which has  a function for this, called *hscroll*:

```
pyautogui.hscroll(10)
```

I didn't find something similar in *pywinauto*

Comment: Thanks for finding this! Filed [issue #392](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/392).

Answer (score 0):

.wheel_mouse_input(wheel_dist=100)  seems to have done the trick for me.  I've only checked this in Word but hopefully it will also work in Excel.

Comment: It's ok.. This was an issue that was fixed - https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/392